# Different behaviors between GCC and Clang

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, clang

Code:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    unsigned char a = -300.f;
    printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

GCC compiling:

```
g++ test.cpp -o test -std=c++11
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:4:21: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
  unsigned char a = -300.f;
                     ^
```

GCC result:

```
0
```

GCC version:

```
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) 5.4.0 20160609
```

Clang Compiling:

```
clang++ test.cpp -o test -std=c++11
test.cpp:4:21: warning: implicit conversion from 'float' to 'unsigned char' changes value from 300 to 255
      [-Wliteral-conversion]
        unsigned char a = -300.f;
                      ~    ^~~~~
1 warning generated.
```

Clang result:

```
160
```

Clang version:

```
clang version 3.8.0-2ubuntu4 (tags/RELEASE_380/final)
```

Maybe the standard doesn't define this behavior.

---

After adding `-fsanitize=undefined`：

GCC result (same)：

```
0
```

Clang result (48!?)：

```
test.cpp:4:20: runtime error: value -300 is outside the range of representable values of type 'unsigned char'
48
```

Comment: Remove `maybe` from `Maybe the standard doesn't define this behavior.`, you got your answer.

Comment: You may also want to constrain your question to *which standard* is it you are referring to. In particular, by not adding irrelevant tags.

Comment: Consider `-fsanitize=undefined` in both compilers. Then both will consistently not print any result at all.

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined

Comment: Using uniform initialization like `unsigned char a{-300.f};` will fail to compile.

Comment: @nwp Yes, that's true here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behaviour on converting a **floating point type** to an `unsigned char` where the floating point value is outside the range of the `unsigned char` is *undefined*.

Note this is different to the case where the original type is a wider integral type.